# Merge and save two UIImageViews

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview

My project has two `UIImages`, one named `imageView` and one named `Birdie`.

```
- (UIImage *)addImage:(UIImage *)imageView toImage:(UIImage *)Birdie {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.size);

    // Draw image1
    [imageView drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.size.width, imageView.size.height)];

    // Draw image2
    [Birdie drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, Birdie.size.width, Birdie.size.height)];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return resultingImage;
}

-(void)captureScreen{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(resultingImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

This is my code, the `captureScreen` button is to save the image. It's not working because `resultingImage` is undeclared, but I'm pretty new to Xcode so I don't know how to fix this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

Override this `-(void)captureScreen:` method to `-(void)captureScreen:(UIImage*)imageToSave`

then in your button action like

`- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender{ 
[self captureScreen:[self addImage:imageViewImage toImage:BirdieImage]] 
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
  `resultingImage`
```

Is not a global variable its scope is limited to only `- (UIImage *)addImage:(UIImage *)imageView toImage:(UIImage *)Birdie` method you have to call this method and use returned object by this method.

```
-(void)captureScreen{
     UIImage *resultingImage = [self addImage:yourFirstImage toImage:yourSecondImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(resultingImage, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Tim,
one point you should remember tht we must not call 'drawRect' method directly.
It would be called by the system.
So here you should use other methods available for UIImage.
you can use 'imageNamed:' method....

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I tried to replace the 'captureScreen' code with the one you've posted. But the application just seems to crash when I push the button.

Thanks again!

Comment: At the top code (-UIImage...):"Local declaration of 'imageView' hides instance variable."
"Local declaration of 'Birdie' hides instance variable." At the part of the buttonvoid: "incompatible Objective-C types 'struct UIImageView *', expected 'struct UIImage *' when passing argument 1 of 'addImage:toImage:' from distinct Objective-C type". Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Tim, you can not use UIImage's like this....
You have to use UIImageView....
1.create a UIImageView object.... Using initWithFrame: method

2. Create UIImage obj with method i mentioned earlier

3. Set this image on UIImageView object

4.add this UIImageView obj on ur view

5. Create another
UIImageView object , but with diff frame so tht both UIImageView objects do nt overlap

6. Do other stuff : create UIImage obj and set it to this UIImageView obj

now add this second UIImageView on ur view.
After tht u can GetGraphic context and use it

Comment: also u are using wrong methds with UIImage object.....[drawRect]...... It is the cause of crash....

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I'm just a rookie so I don't understand the whole thing. What do I have to replace the drawRect for so it doesn't crashes and the whole thing works? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I've got it so far now that it sometimes save the image and sometimes it doesn't. When it doesn't it sometimes gives the error: "Failed to encode image for saved photos". And when it does it does save it, the overlaying image is saved as coordinate 0,0. But I changed the coordinate line to: Birdie.center.x, Birdie.center.y .. So I don't know what to do now..